# Como popular listiview de varias TABs com informações vindas de um BD SQLite

Tags: android

Estou trabalhando em um aplicativo que apresenta todos os jogos do campeonato brasileiro.

Quero que em cada tab apareça os jogos de uma rodada, exemplo:

tab1 (rodada1)

tab38 (rodada38)

Com esse objetivo criei umas tabs usando a Sherlock.

Os jogos vem da Base de dados que criei no SQLite.

Minha duvida é como apresentar as rodadas em cada tab?

Já tenho a classe que busca os dados do bd e joga eles em uma lista e depois o adapter se encarrega de popular um ListView que esta dentro das tabs.

Como colocar em cada TAB uma rodada diferente?

Segue meus códigos principais: MainActivity.java

```html
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    private ActionBar actionBar;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private int rodadas=38;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        actionBar= getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(onPageChangeListener);

        viewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),preparaTab(1)));
        addActionBarTabs();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.item_table:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Tabela", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }


    private List<Jogo> preparaTab(int rodada) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        BD bd = new BD(this);
        return bd.buscar(rodada);
    }

    private ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener onPageChangeListener = new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            super.onPageSelected(position);
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            viewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),preparaTab(position+1)));
        }
    };



    private void addActionBarTabs() {
        //actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

        for (int i=0;i<rodadas;i++) {
            ActionBar.Tab tab = actionBar.newTab().setText("Rodada "+(i+1))
                    .setTabListener(tabListener);
            actionBar.addTab(tab);
        }
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    }

    private ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        }
    };
}
```

ViewPagerAdapter.java

```html
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private final int PAGES = 9;
    private List<Jogo> jogoList;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Jogo> jogoList) {
        super(fm);
        this.jogoList = jogoList;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        return new TabFragment(jogoList);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGES;
    }
}
```

Da forma que esta o código acabei com a performance, pois cada vez que desliso para a próxima TAB a aplicação trava pois é feita uma consulta para popular o listview da próxima tab.

Comment: Tens de passar uma lista já com os jogos já selecionados para cada TAB.

Comment: Em teoria eu retornaria todas as rodadas de uma vez  e já montaria as listviews e os fragments antes da aplicação finalizar a inicialização? Pode me dar um exemplo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em resumo eu criei um AsyncTask que é chamado no onCreate, nele eu importo todos os jogos. Criei uma classe chamada rodada que recebe uma lista de jogos. Desta forma importando todos os jogos de uma vez, não precisarei acessar o bd toda vez para criar a lista da rodada resolvendo o problema de performance.

Comment: Isso foi a solução do problema ou um complemento da pergunta? Se é a solucao, poderia detalhar mais?